# Intellij: Need a way to speed up gradle import and build process

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Java microservices project with 37 different modules (and growing). Whenever my versions change, Intellij reimports the Gradle build info and rebuilds all of them, including downloading the dependencies. This takes almost TWO hours! What can be done to speed this up?

I gave the compiler 3g of RAM hoping that would help, but the difference is minimal. Are there any other settings I can tweak?

Just wanted to add that I'm on a 64-bit, 6 core box, so I should certainly be able to build faster than this.

Comment: Does building project from Build > Build Project also takes 2 hours ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Does it help if you toggle the Offline mode in the Gradle tool window? Does it help if you [disable gradle build delegation](https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png)?

Comment: I'll try both of those, thanks!